# explode php into different lines

Tags: php, explode

I have a string that I cannot edit. each name is separated by a `,`

```
$json = explode(",", file_get_contents("http://api.easyjquery.com/ips/?ip=".$theirip."&full=true"));
```

I am storing this into a txt document just as a test project. I was wondering after I explode it how would I would make each content that was seperated by a , to go to a new line using `\n` so it isn't all on one line.

hope this made sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :

```
$result = implode("\n",$json);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
$json = explode(",", file_get_contents("http://api.easyjquery.com/ips/?ip=".$theirip."&full=true"));
$text = implode("\n",$json);
```